# Can we use other emulator rather than the 'slow' native Android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, smartface.io

Is it possible to use other emulator directly from smartface? I'm trying to not using the default native android emulator which we know is very slow in performance.
I already try using other emu, and connecting them using adb, but as I'm still using the community version of smartface, it counts as on-device emulation (which is not provided fully for community users).
Yes, even it's emulator (such as bluestack, genymotion, etc), the adb makes them connected as a physical device, not emulator known by smartface app studio.

Thanks all...

Comment: Yes, you can use virtual device emulators for Android. 
By the way, I don't agree with your performance comment. For me, virtual device emulator is always slower than the native one.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what I meant is the virtual emulator that comes standard from android AVD. It feels very slow since starting the emulator. Well maybe I just didn't configure it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use real devices.

Otherwise you can use GenyMotion software which is better than Android Virtual Emulator.

You can read more about from the [guides](http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/genymotion/).

Comment: GenyMotion, and other similar are good. But they're still considered as On-Device emulator by smartface. I was wondering if there is such emulator that can be recognized as emulation by smartface, like when smartface recognize the android virtual device as a pure emulator, not on-device emulator (which not allowed for community edition of smartface)